# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma while Inserting rows in a table

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

```
String s1 = Fname.getText();
String s2 = Lname.getText();
String s3 = usr.getText();
String s4 = psswd.getText();
String s5 = Eml.getText();
String s6 = sx.getText();
String s7 = DOB.getText();
String s8 = mob.getText();
String s9 = city.getText();

if((s3 != null) && (s4 != null))
    try
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO SIGNUP " + "(F_NAME varchar2(10), L_NAME varchar2(10), USER_ID varchar2(10), PASSWD varchar2(15), EMAIL varchar2(30), SEX varchar2(7), DOB Date, MOB_NO varchar2(10), CITY varchar2(15))" + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        String user = "system";
        String psswd = "sys123";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user , psswd);
        //System.out.println(query);

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, s1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, s2);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, s3);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, s4);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, s5);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, s6);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, s7);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, s8);
        preparedStatement.setString(9, s9);
        int temp = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            String msg = "Congratulations! Registration Successful...";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b1, null, msg, temp);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Well, I know it's a duplicate question and has been asked many times.But, I'm still unable to fix it up. I've checked every possible errors like whitespaces, singlequotes but it's still not working. The UserID and Password fields are not Nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the type definitions `varchar2(10)` etc. from the INSERT.

```
"INSERT INTO SIGNUP " + "(F_NAME, L_NAME, USER_ID ...)"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO SIGNUP " + "(F_NAME , L_NAME , USER_ID , PASSWD , E_MAIL, SEX , DOB Date, MOB_NO , CITY )" + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

I suggest this is a better way. If you are using Java why don't you use Entity JPA 2.2. It is going to manage you the CRUD operations.

Comment: What is the reason on concatenation operations then?

Comment: Well, I'm a new-bee in java.so, don't know much about it. The "missing comma error" is solved but a new one arised saying: "ORA-00904: "E_MAIL": invalid identifier". :( @AmirBuzo

Comment: Finally, I got it.. E_MAIL is a reserved keyword in Oracle.So,you need to alter the name. A big releif.. :))

Comment: If there's an error with your answer (E_MAIL being a reserved word), please edit your answer to be correct, in case someone finds it but doesn't read through the comments.